# Prove if a relation is left-total and right-unique

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

In this exercise, we are dealing with [Tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)  sets.

So let $M \subset P (A × \mathbb{N})$ be the set of all legal tuple sets. P (X) denotes the power set of a set X. Now, Let the tuple set operation be defined as $+$ so that $+$: M × M → M.

Prove or disprove that + is left-total and right-unique.

These types of relations are uncommon in English, it seems. So, it's a bit difficult for me to understand how to prove it.

To my knowledge, a left-total relation means that, e.g. if $ \forall x \in A$ $\exists y \in N$ $(x,y) \in M$,
i.e. for every $x \in A$ there exists (at least) one $y \in N$, so that $(x,y) \in M$

This exercise is originally in German so I might not have translated it correctly. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $+$ is a function, and functions are just special cases of relations.

Hence, for [left-totality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329904/determining-and-understanding-properties-of-relations-given-the-relation-as-a-s#:%7E:text=informal%20definition%3A%20every%20element%20is%20related%20to%20something.) of $+$, you wish to show that for any pair $(m_1,m_2) \in M \times M$, that we can find $m \in M$ where $m_1+m_2 = m$ (to use the usual conventions for operations). That is, essentially, left-totality for function relations amounts to ensuring each input has an output.

At present, this is not satisfied. How would you define $m_1+m_2$ for two tuples of different sizes? (I assume we add them in the "usual" way, namely pointwise.) For instance, if $(1,2),(1,2,3,4) \in M$, how would $(1,2) + (1,2,3,4)$ be defined? In fact even if $M$ is limited to tuples of the same size, you won't necessarily have the desired property unless $A$ is closed under addition.

[Right-uniqueness](https://is.gd/AJWJlh) is another property expected of functions (notice how these two relate? We're showing $+$ is a function!); namely, any input goes to at most one output. Whenever the addition of tuples is defined, then it inherits this property from that of the addition of elements of $+$ (if present).